# How to unflatten DTO to complex types using conventions

Tags: automapper

I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
public class MyThingDto
{
    public double Position_X { get; set; }
    public double Position_Y { get; set; }
    public double Position_Z { get; set; }

    public double Speed_X { get; set; }
    public double Speed_Y { get; set; }
    public double Speed_Z { get; set; }
}
```

which I want to map into an object that looks like this:

```
   public class MyThing
   {
       public Vector3D Position {get;set;}
       public Vector3D Speed {get;set;}
   }
```

where Vector3D (obviously) looks like this:

```
   public class Vector3D
   {
       public double X {get;set;}
       public double Y {get;set;} 
       public double Z {get;set;}
   }
```

Can it be done with AutoMapper using conventions?